# ViewPager.setAdapter take 200ms to 300ms to execute

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a little UI problem with my ViewPager.

My ViewPager is the center of my UI.

I have a NavigationView with 4 items and a Toolbar with 2 items.

Each time an item of the NavigationView is clicked, I replace the adapter. Therefore I have 4 adapters and only one is causing problems : BrowseAdapter (code is below).

This adapter is filled with a list of Events and provide a Fragment for each Event.

Something good to know is that whatever the size of the eventList is, the setAdapter method of the ViewPager takes at least 150ms to execute, whereas for the other Adapters, it takes only 20 to 50ms to load.

I have tried to put all calls to setAdapter in the `View.post(new Runnable());` method and in an `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` :

- The post method froze the UI
- The AsyncTask changed nothing because I can only call setAdapter on the  UI Thread (in the postExecute method) which is basically the same as calling it without the AsyncTask.

I think this is basically an optimization problem but I can't see where is the problem.

Thank you for you help.

**Here is the code in question :**

*MainActivity :*

```
/*
.
. Import stuff
.
.
.*/

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RequestCallback,
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, FBLoginChanged, LocationListener {


/**
 * The main content view
 */
private CustomViewPager mViewPager;

/**
 * Adapters : One for each feature of the application
 */
private BrowseAdapter mBrowseAdapter;
private CurrentAdapter mCurrentAdapter = new CurrentAdapter(getFragmentManager());
private CalendarAdapter mCalendarAdapter = new CalendarAdapter(getFragmentManager());
private SettingsAdapter mSettingsAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(getFragmentManager());

/**
 * The action bar of the application
 */
private Toolbar mToolbar;
/**
 * TabLayout provide the new Material Design tab navigation
 */
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
/**
 * Side navigation given by a NavigationView instead of a NavigationDrawer
 * to support Material Design
 */
private NavigationView mNavigationView;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

/**
 * List of all events.
 */
private ArrayList<Event> mEventList = new ArrayList<Event>();

/**
 * Provide different way of browsing through the events
 */
private enum BrowseType {
    DEFAULT,
    POPULAR,
    RANDOM
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    /*.
    .
    . Initialization stuff
    .
    .*/

    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Closing drawer on item click
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                mTabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mBrowseAdapter.setBrowsingType(BrowseType.DEFAULT);
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mBrowseAdapter);
                break;
            case R.id.favs:
                mTabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mCurrentAdapter);
                break;
            case R.id.calendar:
                mTabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mCalendarAdapter);
                break;
            case R.id.setting:
                mTabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mSettingsAdapter);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mBrowseAdapter = new BrowseAdapter(this.getFragmentManager(), mEventList);

    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        // Unused
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab) {
            switch(tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0:
                mBrowseAdapter.setBrowsingType(BrowseType.DEFAULT);
                break;
            case 1: 
                mBrowseAdapter.setBrowsingType(BrowseType.POPULAR);
                break;
            default: // Unused
                break;
            }
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mBrowseAdapter);
        }
        @Override
        // Unused
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab) {

        }

    });

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mBrowseAdapter);
}

}
```

*My adapter :*

```
private class BrowseAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
private BrowseType browseType = BrowseType.DEFAULT;
private HashMap<Integer, EventFragment> fragmentReferenceMap = new HashMap<Integer, EventFragment>();

public BrowseAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,
        ArrayList<Event> mEventList) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

public void setBrowsingType(BrowseType type) {
    this.browseType = type;
    this.commitChanges();
}

public Event getEventById(int id) {
    for(Event event : eventList) {
        if(event.getId() == id)
            return event;
    }
    return null;
}

public void setJSONData(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Event event = new Event();
            event.setId(obj.getInt("id"));
            event.setName(obj.getString("name"));
            event.setShort_description(obj.getString("short_desc"));
            event.setLong_description(obj.getString("long_desc"));
            event.setPlace(obj.getString("place").split(";")[0]);
            Location loc = new Location("");
            loc.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(obj.getString("place")
                    .split(";")[1]));
            loc.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(obj.getString("place")
                    .split(";")[2]));
            event.setLocation(loc);
            event.setDate(obj.getString("date"));
            eventList.add(event);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getJSONData() {
    JSONArray toReturn = new JSONArray();
    for (Event event : eventList) {
        JSONObject tmp = new JSONObject();
        try {
            tmp.put("name", event.getName());
            tmp.put("short_desc", event.getShort_description());
            tmp.put("long_desc", event.getLong_description());
            tmp.put("id", event.getId());
            tmp.put("date", event.getDate());
            tmp.put("place",
                    event.getPlace()
                    + ";"
                    + String.valueOf(event.getLocation()
                            .getLatitude())
                            + ";"
                            + String.valueOf(event.getLocation()
                                    .getLongitude()));
            toReturn.put(tmp);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return toReturn.toString();
}

public boolean addItem(Event item) {
    return eventList.add(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public Event removeAt(int position) {
    return eventList.remove(position);
}

public void commitChanges() {
    this.sort();
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void sort() {
    Log.d("SORT", browseType.name());
    Collections.sort(eventList, new Comparator<Event>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Event arg0, Event arg1) {
            float dis1 = arg0.getLocation().distanceTo(
                    LocationProvidor.getInstance().getLastLocation());
            float dis2 = arg1.getLocation().distanceTo(
                    LocationProvidor.getInstance().getLastLocation());
            int userNumber1 = Integer.parseInt(arg0.getUserNumber());
            int userNumber2 = Integer.parseInt(arg1.getUserNumber());
            switch(browseType) {
            case DEFAULT:
                return (int) (dis1 - dis2);
            case POPULAR:
                return userNumber2 - userNumber1;
            case RANDOM:
                return new Random().nextInt();
            default:
                return 0;
            }
        }

    });
}

public void empty() {
    eventList.clear();
}

@Override
public EventFragment getItem(int position) {
    EventFragment frag = EventFragment.newInstance(eventList.get(position));
    frag.setIsCurrents(mCurrentAdapter.containsEventId(eventList.get(position).getId()));
    fragmentReferenceMap.put(position, frag);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    fragmentReferenceMap.remove(position);
    Log.d("fr.blopper.app", "destroy " + position);
}

public EventFragment getFragment(int position) {
    return fragmentReferenceMap.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return eventList.size();
}
}
```

*And CustomViewPager (I have created it only to measure the time taken by setAdapter):*

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;


public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

public CustomViewPager(Context c) {
    super(c);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context c, AttributeSet as) {
    super(c, as);
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(PagerAdapter adapter) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d("TAG", "Custom time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}
}
```

Comment: Use method tracing in Android Studio to determine where you are spending your time.

Comment: @CommonsWare unfortunately, i am not using Android Studio (too slow on my computer), I build with Gradle but I write with Atom editor.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, it has nothing to do with the ViewPager.

The Fragments provided by the Adapter were making a call to a Google API which was slow to answer.